# Create an object if one is not found

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I create an object if one is not found? This is the query I was running:

```
  @event_object = @event_entry.event_objects.find_all_by_plantype('dog')
```

and I was trying this:

```
  @event_object = EventObject.new unless @event_entry.event_objects.find_all_by_plantype('dog')
```

but that does not seem to work. I know I'm missing something very simple like normal :( Thanks for any help!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use built in query methods like `find_or_create_by` or `find_or_initialize_by`

```
@event_object = @event_entry.event_objects.find_or_create_by(plantype:'dog')
```

This will find an `@event_entry.event_object` with `plantype = 'dog'` if one does not exist it will then create one instead.

`find_or_initialize_by` is probably more what you want as it will leave `@event_object` in an unsaved state with just the association and `plantype` set

```
@event_object = @event_entry.event_objects.find_or_initialize_by(plantype:'dog')
```

This assumes you are looking for a single `event_object` as it will return the first one it finds with `plantype = 'dog'`. If more than 1 `event_object` can have the `plantype ='dog'` within the `@event_entry` scope then this might not be the best solution but it seems to fit with your description.

Comment: @MechDog updated my answer as you were selecting it please note I added `find_or_initialize_by` which might be more what you want. This will hold the object in an unsaved state in case other attributes are needed. Also there is a `find_or_create_by!` which will raise in the event the object is invalid.

Comment: @AlexWayne no they are not actually `find_or_create_by_plantype` is depreciated. `find_or_create_by(plantype:...)` is still very much supported."find_or_create_by_... **can be rewritten using find_or_create_by(...)**."

Comment: @AlexWayne no problem had the same discussion with someone a little while ago. Sometimes the sugary syntax differences cause confusion  when it comes to depreciation.

Answer (score 3):

`find_all` style methods return an array of matching records. That is an empty array if no matching records are found. And an empty is *truthy*. Which means:

```
arr = []
if arr
  puts 'arr is considered turthy!' # this line will execute
end
```

Also, the dynamic finder methods (like `find_by_whatever`) are [officially depreacted](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations) So you shouldn't be using them.

You probably want something more like:

```
@event_object = @event_entry.event_objects.where(plantype: 'dog').first || EventObject.new
```

But you can also configure the event object better, since you obviously want it to belong to `@event_entry`.

```
@event_object = @event_entry.event_objects.where(plantype: 'dog').first
@event_object ||= @event_entry.event_objects.build(plantype: dog)
```

In this last example, we try to find an existing object by getting an array of matching records and asking for the first item. If there are no items, `@event_object` will be `nil`.

Then we use the `||=` operator that says "assign the value on the right if this is currently set to a falsy value". And `nil` is falsy.  So if it's `nil` we can build the object form the association it should belong to. And we can preset it's attributes while we are at it.